# Running a cmd command within a C++ program using system() function

Tags: c++, windows, batch-file

I want to move a file from its directory to C:\Program files\ so I ran this line of code

```
system("copy /y \"%~dp0\\myfile\" \"C:\\Program files\"");
```

When compiling and executing this line of code and running it as an admin, it returns an error saying "The system cannot find the path specified."
Even though, it runs fine as a .bat script.
What's the problem ?!

Comment: `%~dp0` means nothing by itself. Open a command prompt and type `dir "%~dp0"` and hit enter. What does it say then? `%~dp0` is only useful in a `FOR` command in a batch file. `system()` is not a batch file.

Comment: Comment/Advice: *Never* use `system()`. It is too hard to control the environment the sub-process runs in. It's too hard checking/parsing the return value and output from the sub-process after the fact. It opens you up to a multitude of security issues. `system()` should be avoided like the plague.

Comment: c++17 offers the [`filesystem`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/filesystem) standard library header.

Comment: `%~dp0` is only valid inside a batch file. You cannot use it if you don't have a batch file.

Comment: By the way hardcoded paths like `C:\Program files` are not acceptable in real software.

Comment: n.m, what do you propose as a replacement of C:\Program files ?!

Comment: @AbdulrahmanMahdaly Never hard-code system paths, use `SHGetFolderPath()` or `SHGetKnownFolderPath()` to lookup the paths dynamically at runtime instead. They are based on user configuration. But why are you using `system()` to invoke a CMD process to handle this operation, instead of using an API directly in your code? Look at APIs like `CopyFile/Ex()`, `SHFileOperation()`, `IFileOperation::CopyItem()`, etc.

Comment: Thanks guys for your valuable advices.. I'll take them into account.

Comment: When somebody publish question on Stackoverflow, it should be as simple as possible.
Single line where is a problem is perfect. Like @AbdulrahmanMahdy did.
Using function like `SHGetKnownFolderPath()` is right way in real life comercial softwere, but when troubleshooting it's only unnecessary noise.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seem to be with `%~dp0`.
`system()` function is not awere of it.
Possibe solution is to create string containing real filename and give that to `system()`.
Example:

```
system("copy file1.txt file2.txt");
```

Comment: no the real solution to avoid `system()` at all cost and call the native API to copy instead, such as [CopyFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-copyfile) on Windows. There's no reason to spawn a new shell just to copy and don't even check its result